# Send Slash Commands Embeds Choices | Discord.js v14

Tags: discord, discord.js, embed, slash

I'm trying to make a Slash Command embeds command with option choices when you select an embed choice it will send the embed that is for that embed option I've tried to do it but I'm not sure if I know how to do it I need some help please

I'm expecting a embeds slash command what when you select an option choice it will send the corresponding embed for that embed choice.

Comment: _"I've tried to do it"_ What have you tried? Can you post your code?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros I can't find the code anymore that I did I think the my friend deleted the code bc we are making a Discord bot together!